# rails: loading image before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How do you show a loading image while your page is loading?

Could you guys point me in the right direction? Ive got a rails application that utilizes some jquery and javascript. It is taking awhile to load the page. Most likely because I make several SQL queries with embedded ruby code in my javascript.

Right now when users click on a link to go to that particular site, nothing happens for a few seconds and then the whole page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a loading page by having an overlapping default div with a loading animation in it in front of everything. Then when your Javascript is finished, have a callback that will hide the loading div.

However, I would say that 90% of the time when you need a page loading animation, you should think of ways to lazy load (load at a later time) as much of the processing as possible. Try to avoid page delays at all costs.

Comment: is there a way I can delay my javascript from running?

Comment: You could put the script with the AJAX call at the very bottom of the page, so it would fire last after everything has already loaded. I would also break up the Ruby call into as small pieces as possible, then trigger the pieces via events as necessary.